# Is there a way to add JS to a page node Head tag directly from the page editor?

Tags: 7, javascript, google-analytics

I am using [Google Experiments](https://www.google.com/analytics/web) for split testing and I need a different script for each page.

Adding a different script per page can be tedious if there is no way to add the script from the page editor.

[JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) or [Tracking Code](https://www.drupal.org/project/tracking_code), can only add JS to the Head of a page via a third settings page, where one needs to insert the URL of the page along with the code.

I don't want to create a rule for each page and then set one URL for each rule.

Is there a module that puts a textarea in the editor's page that will make this happen?

Something like [Code Per Node](https://www.drupal.org/project/cpn) but it doesn't allow the `<script>` tag to be inserted in the textarea field on the node page editor, which can't be used.

the JS code to insert for Google Experiments is:

```
<!-- Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
<script>function utmx_section(){}function utmx(){}(function(){var
k='xxxxxxx-27',d=document,l=d.location,c=d.cookie;
if(l.search.indexOf('utm_expid='+k)>0)return;
function f(n){if(c){var i=c.indexOf(n+'=');if(i>-1){var j=c.
indexOf(';',i);return escape(c.substring(i+n.length+1,j<0?c.
length:j))}}}var x=f('__utmx'),xx=f('__utmxx'),h=l.hash;d.write(
'<sc'+'ript src="'+'http'+(l.protocol=='https:'?'s://ssl':
'://www')+'.google-analytics.com/ga_exp.js?'+'utmxkey='+k+
'&utmx='+(x?x:'')+'&utmxx='+(xx?xx:'')+'&utmxtime='+new Date().
valueOf()+(h?'&utmxhash='+escape(h.substr(1)):'')+
'" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"><\/sc'+'ript>')})();
</script><script>utmx('url','A/B');</script>
<!-- End of Google Analytics Content Experiment code -->
```

Comment: Why do you need different scripts per page? Are the scripts totally different? or just a small part of the script varies?

Comment: Have you tried the [Google Analytics](https://www.drupal.org/project/google_analytics) module?

Comment: @NoSssweat, yes each page differs in the Experiment Key value, my temporary fix to it is to use one Tracking Code module with a replacement token (the key) that has its own field in the page. so one just inserts that key and the page it's ready for Google Experiments.

Comment: Google Analytics does not do that